# How do I release my update (1.1) without ever releasing 1.0 in iTunes Connect?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store-connect

I have an approved app (1.0) on itunesconnect, set to release on March 8th 2012 for the first time. We found a bug, sent an update (1.1). How do I release 1.1, instead of 1.0? If its not possible, what is the best way to minimize the time 1.0 is on sale. If I "publish" the update before the 8th, would it release 1.1 on the 8th, as set in 1.0?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What I've done in this situation is just withdraw the 1.0 binary by clicking the Reject This Binary button, and then submit a new 1.0 binary with the bug fixed. See the iTunes Connect Developer Guide, in the section called "Rejecting Your Binary" - according to that documentation, you can do this even if your app is approved for sale.

(I suppose you could call the new binary 1.1 if you wanted to, but if 1.0 is withdrawn and the public never sees it, there seems little point - though that's probably just a matter of aesthetics.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the option to reject the binary is not there anymore for apps that are approved for the first time (looks like you can only reject updates).

Answer (score 1):

Sense your app has already been approved you have two options. Either you can hope that your 1.1 is finished with review by the 8th and release 1.0 and 1.1 within minutes of each other, which would minimize the time that the buggy version spends on the store or the other option is too as stated above, to remove 1.0 from the store. Seeing as the app has already be approved the removal process is a little different. Instead of rejecting the binary go to your apps page in iTunes Connect >>> Rights & Pricing >>> Specific Stores >>> DESELECT ALL

This will remove the app from the App Store!

[image]

Comment: the app is not currently on sale, so deselecting doesnt help. if you mean deselect all stores, publish, then launch update on all stores on march 8th, that works, but we will not be on the new games list (i have tired it before). As for minutes of each other, I believe thats the way to go if you are doing a manual release.  But we want to release it on the 8th automatically...and since you cant set a specific time, do I just set both versions to release on the 8th?